# How to orbit around the Z-axis in 3D

Tags: c++, math, geometry, openframeworks

I'm primarily a Flash AS3 dev, but I'm jumping into openframeworks and having trouble using 3D (these examples are in AS)

In 2D you can simulate an object orbiting a point by using `Math.Sin()` and `Math.cos()`, like so

```
function update(event:Event):void
{
    dot.x = xCenter + Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180) * range;
    dot.y = yCenter + Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180) * range;
    angle+=speed;
}
```

I am wondering how I would translate this into a 3D orbit, if I wanted to also orbit in the third dimension.

```
function update(event:Event):void
{
    ...
    dot.z = zCenter + Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180) * range;
    // is this valid?
}
```

An help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the plane of the orbit parallel to the x-y plane? If not, you need to know the orientation of the plane.  If yes, then `z` doesn't change.

Comment: Perhaps start out by giving 3 points that are on the orbit's plane but not on the same line.

Comment: The code you have *does* orbit around the z-axis. You probably mean that you want an orbit not in the x--y plane or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

If you are orbiting around the z-axis, you are leaving your z-coordinate fixed and changing your x- and y-coordinates.  So **your first code sample is what you are looking for**.

To rotate around the x-axis (or y-axes), just replace `x` (or `y`) with `z`.  Use `Cos` on whichever axis you want to be 0-degrees; the choice is arbitrary.

If what you *actually* want is to orbit an object around a point in 3d-space, you'll need two angles to describe the orbit:  its *elevation angle* and its *inclination angle*.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Equations_in_R3) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates).
For reference, those equations are (where θ and φ are your angles)

> x = x<sub>0</sub> + *r* sin(θ) cos(φ)
>   y = y<sub>0</sub> + *r* sin(θ) sin(φ)
>   z = z<sub>0</sub> + *r* cos(θ)

Answer (score 1):

I would pick two unit perpendicular vectors v, w that define the plane in which to orbit, then loop over the angle and pick the proper ratio of these vectors v and w to build your vector p = av + bw.

More details are coming.

EDIT:

This might be of help

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_equation

EDIT: I think it is actually

center + sin(angle) * v * radius1 + cos(angle) * w * radius2

Here v and w are your unit vectors for the circle.

In 2D they were (1,0) and (0,1).

In 3D you will need to compute them - depends on orientation of the plane.

If you set radius1 = radius 2, you will get a circle. Otherwise, you should get an ellipse.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll plug this in and see what I get, then I'll mark it up

Answer (score 1):

If you are orbiting around Z axis, then you just do your first code, and leave Z coordinate as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the orbit to happen at an angled plane and don't mind it being elliptic you can just do something like `z = 0.2*x + 0.2*y`, or any combination you fancy, after you have determined the x and y coordinates.